# What is the difference between PropertyChangedEventHandler and NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I think both are same, but why are both used in the same method? I think there is a minor difference. Here is some code to show the difference between the two:

```
private void LoadItemListing()
{
    _items = new ObservableCollection<SalesItemListingViewModel>();

    foreach (ItemListing x in _sales.Items)
    {
        SalesItemListingViewModel itemListing = new SalesItemListingViewModel(x);
        _items.Add(itemListing);
        _itemAmountSum += itemListing.Amount;

        itemListing.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(itemListing_PropertyChanged);
    }

    _items.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_items_CollectionChanged);
}
```

And for itemListing_PropertyChanged:

```
void itemListing_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Amount")
    {
        ItemAmountSum = 0;
        foreach (SalesItemListingViewModel x in Items)
            ItemAmountSum += x.Amount;
    }
}
```

And this code for _items_CollectionChanged:

```
void _items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        SalesItemListingViewModel newItemListingViewModel = e.NewItems[0] as SalesItemListingViewModel;
        newItemListingViewModel.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(itemListing_PropertyChanged);
    }
    else if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        ItemAmountSum = 0;
        foreach (SalesItemListingViewModel x in Items)
            ItemAmountSum += x.Amount;
    }

    RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
}
```

I think there is a difference, but I am not sure. Can somebody please explain any difference?

Comment: "plz" don't say "plz"... are you in such a hurry that you can't write the whole word?

Comment: i remember it and from next time i will not write  it.

Comment: That sample code is rather buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PropertyChanged` signals that the *value of a property* has changed. The `CollectionChanged` event signals that the *content of a collection* has changed (not the collection itself: it's still the same collection instance, but elements have been added/removed/replaced).

Comment: sender means object who raise the event.but i never use sender like eventargs' e.action,etc.have u ever used sender?in which context?

Comment: @prjndhi, it's useful when you use the same method to handle events from several objects (e.g. several buttons with the same event handler for Click, and you need to know which button was clicked)